# Get mac address for remote computer under NT4 in C

Tags: c, mac-address, nt4

Is it possible to determine the MAC address of the originator of a remote connection under Windows NT 4? The remote PC opens a socket connection into my application and I can get the IP address. However I need to determine the MAC address from the information available from the socket such as the IP address of the remote device.

I have tried using `SendARP` but this doesn't seem to be supported in Windows NT4.

Comment: The `SendARP()` function is available beginning with Windows 2000 according to Microsoft MSDN on-line [IP Helper Functions -> SendARP function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366358(v=vs.85).aspx). See also [C++ SendARP returns wrong mac address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277659/c-sendarp-returns-wrong-mac-address).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try GetIpNetTable. This function is documented as supported as of NT 4.0 SP4.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the machine isn't *too* remote.  MAC addresses will only be known for the local network (subnet).