# C++ SendARP returns wrong mac address?

Tags: c++

im trying to retrieve the mac address of devices on my lan and im using the SendARP function to do this  but for some weird reason it is giving me the wrong mac address, im telling it to get the mac of my laptop that is also on lan but it does not work :/

link to SendARP function(MSDN): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

the mac of the laptop is really: e0:94:67:18:a7:dc
Mac output by SendARP: e9:ad:2d:01:c8:11

this is the function i created to simply fetch the mac from an ip address :P

```
BYTE* GetMacAddress(IPAddr destination, IPAddr source) {
Sleep(500);
ULONG DestMacAddr[2];
ULONG PhysicalLength = 6;

memset(&DestMacAddr, 0xff, sizeof(DestMacAddr));

DWORD returnValue = SendARP(destination, source, &DestMacAddr, &PhysicalLength);

if(returnValue == NO_ERROR) {
    cout << "Fetched destination mac" << endl;
}else {
    printf("Error: %d\n", returnValue);

    if(returnValue == ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME) {
        printf("ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME\n trying to fetch mac address...");
        return GetMacAddress(destination, source);
    }

    if(returnValue == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
        printf("ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW\n");
    }

    if(returnValue == ERROR_GEN_FAILURE) {
        printf("ERROR_GEN_FAILURE\n");
    }

    if(returnValue == ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) {
        printf("ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER\n");
    }

    if(returnValue == ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER) {
        printf("ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER\n");
    }

    if(returnValue == ERROR_NOT_FOUND) {
        printf("ERROR_NOT_FOUND\n");
    }

    if(returnValue == ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
        printf("ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED\n");
    }
}
BYTE *bMacAddr = (BYTE *) &DestMacAddr;

return bMacAddr;
```

}

i was thinking it might be because it is network byte order or something but nothl() did not work either :/ please help me out here :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
BYTE *bMacAddr = (BYTE *) &DestMacAddr;

return bMacAddr;
```

You're returning a pointer to some thing that's on the stack of your GetMacAddress() function, which will be gone when the function ends.

Comment: what should i do then ? i need to return it in an array :/

Comment: @Paze Have the caller pass in the array (But then you need to fix all your code that takes the address of the.array, e.g. `memset(&DestMacAddr, 0xff, sizeof(DestMacAddr));` is strictly wrong, it should be `memset(DestMacAddr, 0xff, sizeof(DestMacAddr));`). Or dynamically allocate the array with malloc and return that. .e.g `BYTE* p = malloc(sizeof DestMacAddr); memcpy(p, DestMacAddr, sizeof DestMacAddr); return p;`

Answer (score 0):

Type 'arp -a' on command prompt to see what is MAC address of your laptop on your local arp table. If it is different then the original then type 'arp -d'(With Admin Rights On Vista and Win7/8) to clear arp table and try to check mac again by using yo SendARP App.

Comment: yea my arp cache tells me that the mac is the actual one i am expecting :P the one that is "real" a.k.a this one:e0:94:67:18:a7:dc

Comment: Try to print bMacAddr in GetMacAddress Function. See what result you get as DestMacAddr is on stack and will be destroyed after it leaves its function scope.

Comment: wow it is the correct one O.o then it is because it is living on the stack :D thanks dude, ur a life saver, now i just need to learn how to return arrays xD

Comment: You can create DestMacAddr on Heap and follow the same procedure (some changes like parameter passing to func) will be changed. After you have used it delete it. Or you can concat mac address on GetMacAddress  function and return as string.