# SendARP returning wrong MAC address

Tags: c#, mac-address, arp

I am trying to get the MAC address of another device using the SendARP function and this code:

```
[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int SendARP(System.Net.IPAddress DestIP, int SrcIP, byte[] pMacAddr, ref uint PhyAddrLen);

private void btnMAC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string mac = "";
    IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(IPaddress);

    byte[] macAddr = new byte[6];
    uint macAddrLen = (uint)macAddr.Length;

    int dwRetVal = SendARP(hostEntry.AddressList[0], 0, macAddr, ref macAddrLen);

    if (dwRetVal == 0)
    {
        StringBuilder macAddressString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < macAddr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (macAddressString.Length > 0)
                macAddressString.Append(":");

            macAddressString.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", macAddr[i]);
        }

        mac = macAddressString.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        lblMACaddress.Text = "Invalid";
    }
}
```

The MAC address it is returning is completely wrong. I referenced this question, [C++ SendARP returns wrong mac address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277659/c-sendarp-returns-wrong-mac-address)
but the answer to that question really seemed to be about the return stack being cached when getting out of the function, but I'm doing everything within my function.

I must be missing some basic concepts here that I'm not understanding from other references.

**---EDIT---**
Changed my function to be like this due to possible wrong parameter type:

```
        string ip = txtIP1.Text + "." + txtIP2.Text + "." + txtIP3.Text + "." + txtIP4.Text;
        IPAddress dst = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        int intAddress = BitConverter.ToInt32(dst.GetAddressBytes(), 0);

        byte[] macAddr = new byte[6];
        uint macAddrLen = (uint)macAddr.Length;

        if (SendARP(intAddress, 0, macAddr, ref macAddrLen) != 0)
        {
            lblMACaddress.Text = "SendARP failed.";
            return;
        }

        string[] str = new string[(int)macAddrLen];

        for (int i = 0; i < macAddrLen; i++)
            str[i] = macAddr[i].ToString("x2");

        string mac = string.Join(":", str);
```

Now the issue is when I use my own computer's IP I get the correct MAC but when I use the IP of a different computer on my LAN I get the SendARP failed exception thrown. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Is it an actual MAC address of a device? I would call that a coincidence.

Comment: What is a coincidence? I'm not really sure what you mean. I can look up the MAC on the device using command prompt and then when I use my program and the SendARP function I get a different MAC for that device

Comment: Is the "different MAC" a legitimate MAC address? What happens if you send to that address?

Comment: I don't think so because nothing happens when I send to that address

Comment: What does WireShark show you?

Comment: the same mac address as when I look it up using command prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your p-invoke is wrong. The WINAPI definition of this function passes

this

```
typedef struct {
  union {
    struct {
      u_char s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4;
    } S_un_b;
    struct {
      u_short s_w1,s_w2;
    } S_un_w;
    u_long S_addr;
  } S_un;
} IPAddr;
```

Which I seriously doubt has the same memory layout as the IPAddress class.

Here is a point to get started:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.sendarp

If that doesn't work, you could always marshall the structure yourself using explicit memory layouts, or just use IntPtr.

Comment: I changed my function to use something more like that of the link you posted, and I'm getting odd results. When I use my computer's ip, it returns the correct mac. But when I use the ip of a different computer on my LAN it throws the SendARP failed exception. Any ideas?

Comment: @MikkelBang http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366358(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I've looked at that before, based on my edit above, what should I be doing differently or what am I missing not understanding from your link?

Comment: What is the error code being returned? Then that will get you moving in the right direction. The definitions are in that documentation link.

Comment: It's returning a 67. The article says to use FormatMessage to obtain the error from this code but that seems to be the biggest pain in the butt to use and the example is in C++. I'm still lost here.

Comment: so it seems like you can't get the MAC of a computer if it is off. This might be obvious but I didn't know that

Comment: The 67 is a #define SOME_READABLE_ERROR_CODE 67 somewhere. I am certain it is in the header file definitions on msdn somewhere.

Comment: @MikkelBang glad you found it.